# How to render video files from S3 bucket, using Flask?

Tags: flask, amazon-s3

I'm uploading image files to my S3 bucket and now I want to render the files on the client size using templates. Since they are video files, I want to use the video tag to render them.

I can currently read and display the files from the bucket with the following code:

```
{% for f in files %}
{{ f.key }}<br> #file
{{ f.last_modified }}<hr> #date
{% endfor %}
```

But when I use the video tag to render the key, it's not working. I'm I missing anything here?

```
{% for f in files %}
<video src="{{ f.key }}" type="video/mp4" controls>
{% endfor %}
```

What will be the appropriate way to render the video files for it to be played?
I'm using Flask.

Comment: When you say it's not working, are you getting any error?

Comment: Also, what's the value of f.key and from where do you get it?